# Network icons on all client machines disappeared and public printer scan folder stopped working after running an SMB1-disabling batch file

Tags: network-share, server-message-block, windows-sbs-2011

G'day, everyone.

I have recently tried disabling SMB1 and forcing all clients into using SMB2 by running the following batch file on all client machines:

```
sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb20/nsi
sc.exe config mrxsmb10 start= disabled
```

And I have "turned on" SMB2 on the server by adding a `REG_WORD` called `SMB2` at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters` and setting its value to `1` while changing the value of `SMB1` at the same location to `0`.

Those instructions I have initially found here:

[How to enable and disable SMBv1, SMBv2, and SMBv3 in Windows and Windows Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows-server)

Now, doing all that definitely disabled SMB1, but all the network icons in the Network folder have disappeared in the process. Network items can still be accessed by following all the normal links like `\\server\ClientApps` which is alright for me but not the users. The scan to public folder functionality has ceased working as well (it was using the SMB protocol). I've tried finding out whether the server's actually running SMB2 at all, but 
Windows Small Business Server 2011 Standard does not support the `Get-SmbServerConfiguration` PowerShell command. All clients are running Windows 7 Enterprise, but I've tested this out on Windows 8 and Windows 10 as well, and the network items were missing for those two operating systems as well.

I would like to know what the problem I'm having is and how to fix it without re-enabling SMB1 if possible. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Browsing require SMB1. That's ok, though, as it's trivial to either map a drive for your users or push out a link directly to the share they need to their desktops.

Comment: @EEAA, but doesn't SMB2 which I have "turned on" by running the batch file allow browsing as well? I thought SMB2 encapsulated SMB1 functionality.